# Not able to boot into ubuntu after reinstalling it

Tags: 18.04, grub2, boot-repair

On my system with ssd+hdd, there is windows on ssd and ubuntu on a partion in hdd. I tried installing ubuntu again as blutooth and some others issues are present. Installation is happening properly(boot loader  - /dev/sda, root - /dev/sda5, home - /dev/sda2( home folder for previous ubuntu )). But while booting in grub it is showing previous ubuntu (multiple kernels - i tried installing latest kernel)only, and not able to boot.

Here is a link of error report from boot repair.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Jq2mGRnYZJ/

Can you please help me to rectify this?

Comment: Before you ran Boot-Repair you had two ubuntu entries in UEFI. One using ESP on HDD and on using ESP on SSD. And they then booted different installs. Did you reboot after running Boot-Repair?

Answer (score 0):

### Bluetooth and reinstalling ubuntu

So first off, unless your bluetooth worked then stopped, reinstalling ubuntu would have reinstalled an ubuntu with the same problem.

Hardware support on ubuntu, while convenient because it's plug and play, has less coverage than windows. Newer laptops will often suffer from ubuntu/linux drivers for their wifi/bluetooth/trackpad/keyboard simply not existing because noone has developped them yet.

Since manufacturers rarely see it as their obligation to support anything other than windows, the task of creating the linux drivers will fall to volunteer open source hobbyists.

From there the progression of the driver usually goes : once their driver has been tried and prooved it is made to be compatible with everything else with the in-developement version of the kernel and that kernel usually becomes available either with an update of the system, or if the kernel difference is too big, with a new version of ubuntu.

This means that if you need support for a piece of your hardware **now** you will have to check these solutions in order :

1. Try newer ubuntu if yours isn't already the newest
2. Upgrade kernel further still with ukuu
3. Search for WIP open source drivers to compile from source or patch into your kernel

### Correctly reinstalling ubuntu

If you ever do reinstall ubuntu (as in, you wish to replace the curent one) you should, durring the install process, select "something else"

Selecting "install allongside" in this 2nd install of ubuntu no longer means : "create a windows-ubuntu dual boot" it now means : "create a windows-ubuntu-ubuntu tripple boot".

The option called "something else" will however bring you to a less user friendly interface which is a partitioning window, but there is a way to make the best of it :

You could for example simply use it to delete the ubuntu, swap and efi partition and apply the changes, then simply reboot from the installer and try again and this time select "install allongside" and this time you would get the desired result.

Or you could delete the same partitions and create them again and simply click install.

What you need to do is to first create a 500mb EFI partition and then another partition that has all the defaults (all the leftover size, ext4 and mountpoint `/`).

All in all it's an easy-to-use interface as well.

### About the "mess" boot-repair leaves

Boot repair lists all installed kernels for all installed ubuntus.

After the steps you described, upgrading kernel once on each ubuntu and reinstalling ubuntu, you must have been left with quite a long list.

Reassuringly the firstmost item in the list is now the correct boot choice for booting the ubuntu you installed last (or if it wasn't run from a live-USB, the ubuntu you ran boot-repair from).

What I do to avoid these situations is :

1. Remove old kernels

Bizzarely kernels do not opperate the same way other packages on the system do.
When you update a package on your system both the old and the new version of the package do no co-exist. The old package is deleted and the new version is installed.
But with kernels, both stay on the system. your system is just "plugged-in" to the new kernel and the old one is "dormant" but still installed.

This is actually handy because a kernel upgrade is by far the most breaking change you can make to your system.

Very often people may have a system that runs fine in the moment after a kernel upgrade, but when they attempt to reboot, it will not boot.

For this reason, the old kernel is kept, and when Grub (the ubuntu bootloader) detects a failiure to boot it will show up upon the next try and reveal the option to boot with the old kernel (as well as safe-mode for both kernels)

This will allow the user to boot back into his system using the old kernel that actually works and then he can promptly remove the problematic new kernel.

So what I do when I have prooven my kernel is working by rebooting using it, is to clean up a bit by removing the old kernels using :

```
sudo purge-old-kernels
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

Then you can clean up grub's look by runnning

```
sudo update grub
```

2. The second thing I do is to use grub-customiser

To install :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Which allows me to sort things and delete useless items.

### Now that we know how we got here how do we fix it

My best answer would be to re-run your usb installer once more but this time use "something else" like I said above and delete all of the partitions of the two other ubuntus, and add just one partition for the new one.

Basically start over but with a clean base.